# Flow annotations for recursive function

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, flowtype

I am interested in how to write flow type annotations for such function:

```
const Box = x => ({
  map: f => Box(f(x)),
  fold: f => f(x),
});
```

Type annotations should use Generics, I guess.
Function usage example:

```
const getRandomColor = (): string =>
  Box(Math.random())
    .map(x => x * 0xFFFFFF)
    .map(Math.floor)
    .map(x => x.toString(16))
    .fold(x => `#${x.padStart(0, 6)}`);
```

**P.S.:** If it is impossible, please write a explanation *Why it is impossible*.

Answer of @Isitea unfortunately doesn't fit because he changed the source code and that was not the point.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Is this unclear? I am interested in *how to write flow type annotations?*

Comment: @user633183, Yeah, I am still trying to express it using generics, but I can't get a right solution. Probably, it's really impossible.

Comment: I don't think `Box` has a type (pseudo type annotation): `Box :: a -> {map: (a -> b) -> ?, fold: (a -> b) -> b}`. How would you annotate the type of `map`s return value? This is infinite type recursion.

Comment: @ftor I don't think so, if Box is parameterized with generic type `T` then `f` must be `T -> b` and `map :: (T -> Box<b>)` right?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

@Jared's answer only gets us part of the way, but beware of the things it's *not* enforcing.

How we'd like to write it using flow's [generics](https://flow.org/en/docs/types/generics/)

```
const Box = <A>(x:A): Box<A> => {
  return {
    map: <B>(f: A => B): Box<B> => Box(f(x)),
    fold: <B>(f: A => B): B => f(x),
  }
}
```

Given a simple function and a value of our box, we should be able to verify that the generic type constraint is enforced

```
const numberToString = (x: number) : string =>
  String (x)

const b : Box<string> =
  new Box("1")

b.map(numberToString) // wups! flow doesn't mind!
```

As of now, this is broken and doesn't work in flow. [@mrkev](https://github.com/facebook/flow/issues/6200#issuecomment-384034185) shows us a workaround using a class

```
class Box<A> {
  x: A
  constructor (x: A) { this.x = x }
  map<B>(f: A => B): Box<B> { return new Box(f(this.x)) }
  fold<B>(f: A => B): B { return f(this.x) }
}

const numberToString = (x: number) : string =>
  String (x)

const stringToNumber = (x: string): number =>
  Number (x)

const b : Box<string> =
  new Box("1")

// flow accepts this valid program
b.map(stringToNumber)

// flow rejects this invalid program
b.map(numberToString)
//    ^ Cannot call `b.map` with `numberToString` bound to `f` because number [1] is incompatible with string [2] in the first argument.
```

[@thehogfather](https://github.com/facebook/flow/issues/6200#issuecomment-384080840) shares another alternative with a pre-defined `type`. This is closer to the original form but requires an exhausting amount of typing - 2x what *should* be necessary if flow offered a more competent type system. Anyway it works, so we're not allowed to complain.

```
type Box<A> = {
  map: <B>(f: A => B) => Box<B>,
  fold: <B>(f: A => B)=> B
}

const box = <A>(x:A): Box<A> => {
  return {
    map: <B>(f: A => B): Box<B> => box(f(x)),
    fold: <B>(f: A => B): B => f(x),
  }
}

const numberToString = (x: number) : string =>
  String (x)

const stringToNumber = (x: string): number =>
  Number (x)

const b : Box<string> =
  box("1")

// flow accepts this valid program
b.map(stringToNumber)

// flow rejects this invalid program
b.map(numberToString)
//    ^ Cannot call `b.map` with `numberToString` bound to `f` because number [1] is incompatible with string [2] in the first argument.
```

Comment: Nice. I was wondering if this would be easier with a class given the syntax.

Answer (score 2):

### UPDATE:

Not sure if it's possible, there's a link in the comments to a counter-example for the `map` method.

#### Original Answer:

Yes! It is indeed possible:

```
const Box = <T1>(x:T1): Box<T1> => {
  return {
    map: <T2>(f): Box<T2> => Box(f(x)),
    fold: <T3>(f): T3 => f(x),
  };
};

function takesBoxedString (b: Box<string>):string { return b.fold(s => s + '') }
let boxedNum = Box(3);
let boxedString = Box('foo');
      
takesBoxedString(boxedString); // fine
takesBoxedString(boxedNum);    // compiler complains
```

I didn't know much about flow generics when I started this, but boy howdy do I have a much better appreciation for them now. Here's the [playground](https://flow.org/try/#0MYewdgzgLgBAQiAHjAvDAPAFQIwD4AUiAXDgJRHxJZ6q4wDeAUDDAE4CmUArq2A8yxgBbAIYAHClgBMBAGblKiaXRR0EifLMKlSAGgEtZIADYATSZgDMchVdowtiPQIC+AbkbvGjWVzDAoAEtwGCgRAGt2CHV2UwBlKFZAsABzGHwAIwp1dGgk1NxyPOS0+jZOHj4MgDojM3wIe0aAahgAcjbSGBdGY04YDKRYgDkuIVRFfEtSDz7YQcRYhPy0tHV8NqMQTo9BQUYwyOih+MSSzJPlkpnvUEhYFM4AJREwUxAhAGETEFYJ-AUxVStAE6wAsiIoAALaqsV7vIQA0gGGDVURiQj2ZAAKnSUhg2NxlikOhRaPE+Ah0NqxhAv2Re3JGOQqhgiGqUBAV1S+GwADZSYy6qZMayAAYAYgAJPR2WIRKcRKwoPgAAy6GAClxim57FgHCJRGKnFYXRamUZCGZAA).

Comment: Sure this works but it looks so weird. `Box` is itself paramterized and returns an `Object` with two more type parameters. Why are `T2`/`T3` not part of the `Box` type? And why isn't `f` specified any further. Is this really sound? +1 anyway.

Comment: @ftor doubt it's provably sound in all cases. In flow I don't think it's necessary (possible?) to add the argument types to the signature of a function argument: they're  specified where the function `f` is declared and by implication `f :: T1 -> T2` for `map` etc but the return value must be specified because it defines part of the structure of `Box` (iirc flow uses primarily structural typing).

Comment: I actually studied and implemented row polymorphism in Javascript, which, AFAIK, is a form of structural typing. But there doesn't seem to be any overlap with what flow does. I guess reasonML is the better choice.

Comment: These generics are enforcing less than you think; please do not advise this kind of solution before understanding its pitfalls. See [this example](https://flow.org/try/#0MYewdgzgLgBAQiAHjAvDAPAQQHwwBSIBcmAlIfElrirgN4BQMMATgKZQCuzYMDTTAegEwwIKAEtgrGAG1MAXRjiIYAOSxWYAGYhmUgCYwAFqzaN+AWwCGAB3Lo4uPFvKZUuOGQqIH1D0mcCEhIAGnMmHQAbfXtHfBcYNxp4Lzh3GC0gsKYAX3o8-n56UEhYMA4LACNTABUQAGUoZnEwAHNUfCIRCurmEhhyaGa293NG4fag+mLwaBhKge90IZbW6nMERDwAIgBGbZJpoRgoI2UYCCMQDmiMq3FI+kqAOmsbPHKq2oam1cP6Y6nc6Xa63LT3R6bHYAJgOr1sHx633Gf3oQA) for details

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you want.

If you are using 'flow type checker with babel', I think following code is what you want to get.(Tested with [flow.org](https://flow.org/try/#0PQKgBAAgZgNg9gdzCYAoVBjOA7AzgFzACE4APMAXjAAoxSAuMAgJwEtsBzMAHzGwFcAtgCMApszABKRiXIUAfDTABvVGHVh8cAHJCxzRrSiMAYv2wZ8rHFJllKi2UdrlJUgDRqwASC0BlfDZOQzBjMDMLKxtpJkD2LgVQlylUAF8pAG5MHAIwDlF8ACUAQ2wAEzhBAGE4eAkqahiWeIcvdScwAFli-AALADpmUorBRpSNMH6tXRFxWhdGAVmJGKX9BzpkJQAmZHAAZl23STbJ6aE5rp6B2Dg4FdOpuACgjnm6Rb1xW1jXjdIni94rQAIwANik4w0gLinHeDF+LSasISigABgBiAAkygBAAdimUAsVmPhaGD3GAAEQABipUlSaMyQA) )

```
/* @flow */

const Box = ( x: string | number ): Box => ( {
    toNumber: ( f: Function ): Box => Box( f( x ) ),
    toString: ( f: Function ): string => f( x )
} );
const getRandomColor = (): string =>
    Box( Math.random() )
    .toNumber( ( x: number ): number => x * ( 2 ** 32 ) )
    .toNumber( Math.floor )
    .toString( ( x: number ): string => x.toString( 16 ) )
    .toString( ( x: string ): string => `#${x.padStart( 6, "0" )}` );
```

Comment: Thanks @Isitea for try, but `any` isn't what I want. Your solution is like no solution at all. I want to cover this code strong types like in Ocaml or haskell, like flow is supposed to be. And why are you not sure what I want? :D That's pretty clear - use flow for type coverage :)

Comment: @KonstantinYakushin As your code, several types are assigned at the same name. It's impossible to check static type.

Comment: That's closer to truth. I would like to know why it is impossible. just believe that in strong static typed languages like haskell such code is possible.

Comment: @KonstantinYakushin I edited an answer. If you really want to strict type of variables, It is needed to use variable separately as type. Do not mix type on a variable with "same name".